# How do I connect cc3200launchpad with IBM Watson IoT Platform with Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, cloudant

I  have developed an IoT project with Energia IDE that publish JSON messages to IBM cloudant database. It works well when my launchpad is connected internet with my mobile phone's personal hotspot. However, messages are not published when launchpad connected internet with wi-fi.

The only difference between two code is definition of ssid and password:

```
char ssid[] = ;
char password[] = ;
```

Attempt to connect to network ends up successfully then IP address is obtained after that it couldn't connect to ibm iot client. I cannot see any attempt on: IBM Watson IoT Platform -> Devices -> Logs.

I changed connection security settings: TLS optional also I added my wifi IP to 'White List' but problem still continue.

It looks like program can not connect to MQTT broker because it stays in loop below:

```
while ((rc = client.connect(connectData)) != 0)
{
}
```

Could you please help me. Is there any configuration that I need to do?

Is it possible to encryption cause problem or is it irrelevant with my topic? I do not know about encryption and security methods also which encryption method is used by my modem. If it cause the problem, how can I send the JSON messages to IBM IoT Platform and what do I need to do for connecting my device to IBM IoT Platform with changing security options(TLS with Token Auth. or TLS with certificate Auth.)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you connect over 1883, then TLS should be set on optional. Judging that the connection over the first network is done successfully, I would say that the problem in on the second network which seem to be blocking 1883 port. Make sure that network allows connection over that port. Also, if you want to use TLS, 8883 and 443 should be opened.

Comment: Hello Idan;

Thanks a lot for your response. I have tried to open 1883 port in my modem's web interface. Despite configurations was done, the port was not opened. Is there any other way to open port?

Comment: can you share some details about the modem? maybe I can have a look and advise further